# doubts regarding an "official" example of D3 pack layout

Tags: d3.js

Here is an official example of D3 pack layout: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530
I have two parts that I do not understand:
1:

```
var node = svg.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
      .data(pack.nodes)
```

> //where is "pack.nodes" initialized?

```
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

> //where is "d.x" and "d.y" from? It is not in "flare.json"!

Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend reading the [pack layout documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout). To answer you specific questions ...

> where is "pack.nodes" initialized?

In the linked example the pack layout is initialised as follows:

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

And as per the documentation [pack.nodes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#nodes) is a function that returns the pack layout nodes.

> where is "d.x" and "d.y" from? It is not in "flare.json"!

Checking the same documentation page referenced above, the nodes created by the pack layout each have `x` and `y` properties.

The pack layout and the data from the JSON file are brought together by the D3 data-join. Here is where the magic happens:

```
var node = svg.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack.nodes)
```

This actually uses a feature of the `data` function where rather than passing an array of data items, you can supply a function. This function will be invoked with the data inherited from the parent node. You can see the relevant code here:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/selection/data.js#L98

In this case, the pack layout `nodes` function will be invoked with the `root` data.

Comment: In the pack documentation, "pack.nodes(root) returning the array of nodes associated with the specified root node."   My question here is where is the root parameter for pack.nodes?

Comment: The magic part is even more confusing. Usually the ".data" operator will take concrete data as its parameter (usually an array or an array of objects). In this example, it seems not (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Good point, to understand how it works you have to look at the sourcecode. I've updated the answer with the sneaky 'hidden' behaviour of the data-join!